# Can't get FCM token?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Here is my code

```
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
messaging.requestPermission()
.then(function() {
alert('Notification permission granted.');

return messaging.getToken();

}).then(function(token){
    alert(token);
})
.catch(function(err) {
    alert('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
});
```

i got this errors in the console 
A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
/firebase-messaging-sw.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE

Comment: 1. Are you running on HTTP or HTTPS? It will work only on HTTPS. 2. you have to place the `firebase-messaging-sw.js` file outside the folder (in the root)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZHgr5pQ_prw&index=2&list=PLCakfctNSHkGLCs9az_9PKqW1NY1C5HIU check this video it will help you.